# Creating a Rule (Oracle SQL) to restrict status-code usage based on users' department

Tags: sql, oracle, rules

Our Agency has a data entry problem where users from one department will use case status codes meant to be used by another department. This messes up the integrity of workflow and reporting.
I want to create a rule that will restrict their ability to enter a wrong code (in the GUI application.)

Basically: The Status Codes are (conceptually) divided into 3 chunks:

1. Regulation/Investigation (Codes 01-29)
2. Legal (Codes 30-90)
3. Compliance (Codes 91-301)

Part of the problem is that there are similar process phases (especially between 1 and 2), for example, Regulation has '010 - Review Complete' while Legal has '32 - Attorney Review Complete'. Or worse:
Investigation has '095 - Reopen Case' while Legal has '95 - Reopen Case'.

Unsavvy users will just grab the first code they see that sounds like what they want. *rolls eyes*

The rule would use the stff_loc_tbl (which records the user's division and bureau) and do a look-up against a view (to be created) that would define the set of status codes by bureau_id, where Codes 30-90 are in the set for Legal (bureau_id '119') while all other Codes are in the set (bureau_id <> '119').

Ideally the rule would filter the codes to the user's departmental set. (Optionally, it would either disallow the incorrect code, or display an alert.)

Any suggestions/pointers would be appreciated.
Note: I have never written a rule in sql before (only modified existing rules), so a bit of a novice here...please dumb down your answers accordingly. :)

Thanks in advance.
ForsMiner

The problem has become apparent from querying finding the erroneous entries by querying where the case_hist.evnt_oper_id = stff_loc.stff_oper_id.

I've narrowed down to the case_status_event table which allows a rule to be triggered based on the setting of a status_code.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Different products have different possibilities here.

Comment: `SQL` is a common language used by multiple dbms vendors.  Each vendor has their own set of functions that may work differently from each other.  So please tag your question properly.

Comment: "Create a rule?" What software do you use to handle data entry? What software handles your business rules? How does that software identify the department, and the privileges, of each logged-in user? Does each user have their own Oracle database credentials? We can't even speculate about how you might solve this problem without knowing more. It's definitely a problem worth solving.

Comment: @ O. Jones Versa:Regulation is the user interface for entering and managing application, license, inspection, and enforcement data. It's a very robust application and database. As I mentioned originally, there is a table in the database "case_status_event" where a rule can be triggered upon entry of a specific status code. Note: I'm pretty certain that this is doable; I'm just not sure of exactly HOW to write it.